# Extra columns in workbook - need a good way to delete them

Tags: excel

We populate worksheets from different sources. So we end up with extra empty rows and columns.  There are too many to delete by hand.  Does anyone know of a good way to delete them? maybe some VB code?

I tried to delete them manually but too many

no code to show

I would love to get some way to delte them

Comment: that question demonstrates very little research effort. Not to mention that you did not mark your previous question as answered...

Comment: found an easy way.  hit ctr - end. Select last column. use scroll bar bottom right. move to the left until you see the last column with data, use shift+Left mouse to slect that column.  Click Delete. save the workbook

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if application.CountA(Columns(1).EntireColumn) = 0 then
    Worksheets("My worksheet").Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
end if
```

---

**EDIT:**

Please make some research before coming here. Because if you make some research you can find [this macro](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/11/21/remove-blank-columns-excel/) already made (and [how to use it](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/11/21/remove-blank-columns-excel/)) that seems to suit your needs.

```
Public Sub DeleteEmptyColumns()
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim EntireColumn As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    Set SourceRange = Application.InputBox( _
        "Select a range:", "Delete Empty Columns", _
        Application.Selection.Address, Type:=8)

    If Not (SourceRange Is Nothing) Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For i = SourceRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set EntireColumn = SourceRange.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(EntireColumn) = 0 Then
                EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I found a way to delete extra columns using the slide bar at the bottom of the window.  I still need an answer about deleting extra rows

Answer (score 0):

found an easy way. hit ctr - end. Select last column. use scroll bar bottom right. move to the left until you see the last column with data, use shift+Left mouse to slect that column. Click Delete. save the workbook